# Use BitmapFactory to load cropped image from stream/file

Tags: android, image, crop, bitmapfactory

Is there a simple way to use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` or `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to directly get a center cropped bitmap instead of first loading the complete bitmap and then apply bitmap transformations such as `Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(...)`? I guess when the encoding is known, it should be possible to only read relevant parts of the bitmap which are needed to create the crop.

Basically I want to save memory and prevent out-of-memory situations while loading the complete bitmap only to compute a thumbnail.

If someone could point me into the right direction and give me some key words, I would be very thankful.

For the sake of completeness, here's the code I'm currently using to crop bitmaps, a method I've found on stackoverflow:

```
public Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
    int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();

    // Compute the scaling factors to fit the new height and width, respectively.
    // To cover the final image, the final scaling will be the bigger
    // of these two.
    float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
    float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
    float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);

    // Now get the size of the source bitmap when scaled
    float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
    float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

    // Let's find out the upper left coordinates if the scaled bitmap
    // should be centered in the new size give by the parameters
    float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
    float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

    // The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
    // be
    RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);

    // Finally, we create a new bitmap of the specified size and draw our new,
    // scaled bitmap onto it.
    // TODO: I think we crash here (null pointer exception) when the receiving image is an animated gif
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html)

BitmapRegionDecoder can be used to decode a rectangle region from an image. BitmapRegionDecoder is particularly useful when an original image is large and you only need parts of the image.

To create a BitmapRegionDecoder, call newInstance(...). Given a BitmapRegionDecoder, users can call decodeRegion() repeatedly to get a decoded Bitmap of the specified region.

Example

https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/soundcloud/android/crop/CropImageActivity.java